# How do I make a page work with ssr in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13

My project works successfully in the development environment, but when I move it to the production environment, and after running the npm run build command, nextjs makes some pages run in SSG, while they should be running in SSR since the data on the main page is variable and not static.

[image]

How do I solve the problem?

Thanks.

The home page contains variable data that comes from the database, and is not a page that contains fixed data. It is expected that it runs on the SSR system, not the SSG system.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When asking code related questions, it is always advised to include relevant code (ideally minimal and reproducible) in the question.

Comment: Can you please add more details like, Are you using app router or pages router ? NextJS Version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

> The home page contains variable data that comes from the database, and is not a page that contains fixed data. It is expected that it runs on the SSR system, not the SSG system.

**Possible Cause :**

> Route Segment option `dynamic` which is by default `auto`, causing SSG.

**Solution :**

Add this line in your `page.js` & also in `route.js` if required *(outside of page or route export code)*.

> `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`

**Example :**

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
export default function HomePage() {
  return <h1>Home page</h1>
}
```

By setting this it will cause the page to render dynamically for each request.
*(this line can be added in files page route & layout)*

**Please Read :**

1. **Route Segment Config :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#options
2. **dynamic :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment. If this answer was helpful, then you may mark it as answer.***